# How to make validation border show on Numeric Texbox

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following Numeric Textbox on a form:

```
 @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentLineItem.MortgageAmount).Format("c").Spinners(false)
```

It works great, except for showing validation errors.  The other textboxes on the form which are not Kendo UI shows the red border, but the NumericTextbox and the Date Picker do not.

```
 @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.CurrentLineItem.MortgageDate)
```

In looking at the generated HTML, it looks like this:

```
<span class="k-widget k-numerictextbox input-validation-error"><span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default k-expand-padding"><input type="text" class="k-formatted-value input-validation-error k-input" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: inline-block;"><input class="input-validation-error k-input" id="CurrentLineItem_MortgageAmount" name="CurrentLineItem.MortgageAmount" type="text" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" aria-valuenow="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: none;"><span class="k-select" style="display: none;"><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-n" title="Increase value">Increase value</span></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" title="Decrease value">Decrease value</span></span></span></span></span>
```

Is there some way to show the red border?  The border comes from the 'input-validation-error' class, but as the html shows, it's not being applied to the correct input.